# Is it possible that a trapezium with angles at one side both equal to 60° has all vertices in lattice points?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Let $ABCD$ be a trapezium in a coordinates system. $\angle DAB=\angle ABC=60^\circ$ and $AB$ is parallel to $CD$. Is it possible that all $A, B, C, D$ vertices are lattice points (points with both coordinates being integers)?

Comment: It's not possible. But please share your thoughts.

Comment: In fact, I don't know how to start. I've never solved any tasks concerning possibility of existance of 2D polygons with lattice points as vertices. Some  hints would be appreciated.

Comment: OK, here's a hint: We may suppose $A=(0,0)$. Suppose $B$ and $D$ are lattice points, and that $AB$ and $AD$ make angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ with the $x$-axis. Then $\tan\theta$ and $\tan\phi$ are both rational. But we also have $\phi=\theta+60^\circ$. Is this possible? Try the tangent addition formula, remembering that $\tan 60^\circ=\sqrt 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found [Pick's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) to be very powerful for this sort of proof. In my initial proof attempt, I attempted to produce the sides of the isosceles trapezium to meet at the apex of an equilateral triangle. However, the remainder of my (now deleted) prior proof depended on my being able to show that that apex was also a lattice point, something I have not yet managed.

It is still possible to apply Pick's theorem to the problem by starting with the insight that Parcly Taxel had in his answer below to construct a putative lattice equilateral triangle from the isosceles trapezium by translation of a vertex by a column vector with integer coordinates.

If we let the side of the equilateral triangle be $r$, then its area is $A = \frac 12 r^2 \sin \frac{\pi}{3} = \frac {\sqrt 3}4 r^2$. For a lattice polygon, the squares of all edge lengths are integral (by the Pythagorean theorem).  Hence $A$ is irrational.

However by Pick's theorem, the area $A$ is also rational (an integral multiple of $\frac 12$). $A$ is simultaneously rational and irrational - we've arrived at a contradiction. Therefore a lattice equilateral triangle cannot exist and the original lattice isosceles trapezium with base angles of $60^ \circ$ also cannot exist.

Comment: You have to show that the removed point of the truncated triangle would be at a lattice point, but otherwise a nice proof.

Comment: @Arthur A very good point. I'm "retiring" this answer until I work that part out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the trapezium $ABCD$ exists. Then it would be possible to translate the edge $BC$ such that $C$ and $D$ coincide, and we would then have an equilateral triangle in the integer lattice.

But this latter triangle cannot exist, and the proof can be found [here](http://jdh.hamkins.org/no-regular-polygons-in-the-integer-lattice). In short, if such a triangle exists it would be possible to make a regular hexagon on the integer lattice, but by rotating each of the hexagon's sides 90° about a vertex a smaller hexagon could be made, and we get infinite descent. Thus the hexagon, the triangle and finally the trapezium in the problem cannot exist.

Comment: Regarding the first step (translation of the edge), can it be proven that you'll end up with a lattice equilateral triangle?

Comment: @Deepak Yes. $C$ is translated by an integral vector which is parallel to the parallel lines of the trapezium, so $B$ stays on the original $AB$. The angles are preserved.

Comment: Oh, of course! That's a very simple insight which I missed. And after you arrive at the putative equilateral lattice triangle part, the proof can be completed with Pick's theorem rather than the infinite descent style proof you linked. I hope you don't mind if I alter my previous answer to this simpler one (I'll start after your insight about the equilateral lattice triangle).

Comment: @Deepak Yeah, sure.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are lattice point. Let $E$ be the point on $AB$ such that $DC=EB$. Then $AED$ is an equilateral triangle and $E$ is a lattice point.

Take $A$ as the origin of an Argand plane. If $E$ and $D$ are represented by the complex numbers $e$ and $d$, then $\frac{d}{e}$ should have rational real and imaginary parts, which is impossible.